# Why was heirloom-mailx deleted from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: smtp

It broke my mail agent, since I need to redirect to an external smtp server, and nothing else seems to do that properly.

Answer (score 7):

`heirloom-mailx` is a transitional (meaning "dummy" package that could go away at any time) package that was included in the `s-nail` source package.

Starting with `s-nail` version `14.9.4-1` in Debian, they removed the `heirloom-mailx` package as it was a *transitional* package.  All it did was pull in `s-nail` and then set up a symlink of `heirloom-mailx` to `s-nail`'s binaries.

The changelog for this is here (from http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/s/s-nail/unstable_changelog):

```
s-nail (14.9.4-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * New upstream version 14.9.4
  * Modernize package: DH compat level, Vcs-* URL, Standards-Version
  * Remove heirloom-mailx transitional package (Closes: #876871)
  * Drop patch
  * Simplify debian/rules: Fix parameter setting, use tmp $HOME for tests

 -- Hilko Bengen <bengen@debian.org>  Sun, 01 Oct 2017 11:17:41 +0200
```

The Debian bug for this was [Debian Bug #876871](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=876871) about a non-empty transitional package - transitional packages are supposed to be 'dummy' packages which contain nothing but dependencies on other packages, but in this case it just contained a symlink for compatibility (and was not a valid 'transitional package' per Debian policy).

It looks like the Debian maintainer removed the package since it's not a transitional package.  You should adapt your mail agent (if possible) to use the proper executable rather than the `heirloom-mailx` which only was a symlink to an actual executable.  Failing that, you should consider looking for a new replacement MTA.

Answer (score 3):

`heirloom-mailx` was a transitional package whose only purpose was to pull in `s-nail`. The latter is still available in bionic and newer.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/heirloom-mailx